# Make button work after pressing Enter key

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, but I want it to complete function "calculate" after clicking enter button. How should it be done? there is no problem with this functionality, but I want to try it with enter button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Mini calculator</h3>
   <div class="checker">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Enter first num"> <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="oper" placeholder="enter operation (+,-,/,or*)"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Enter second num"> <br><br>
    <button type="submit"  onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br><br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="refreshPage()">Refresh</button>
   </div>
<p id="message" class="message"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

this is JS source code

```
function calculate(){
    var a,b,c,num1,oper,num2;
    a=document.getElementsByName("num1")[0].value;
    num1=parseInt(a);
    b=document.getElementsByName("oper")[0].value;
    c=document.getElementsByName("num2")[0].value;
    num2=parseInt(c);
    if(b=="+"){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="result is: "+(num1+num2);
    }
    else if(b=="-"){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="result is: "+num1-num2;
    }
    else if(b=="*")
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="result is: "+num1*num2;
    }
    else if(b=="/"){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="result is: "+num1/num2;
    }
}

function refreshPage(){
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: have you tried on keypress?

Comment: `<form>` + `<button type="submit">` + `onsubmit`?

Comment: [Like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/pages/artist/create/create.component.html#L2), but you don't need angular off course, you can do this with good old html...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you need with the `keypress` function

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
  if (event.keyCode == 13){
    calculate();
  }
})
```

`keycode` 13 works for `Enter` and `Intro`

https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/p8oesf61/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the inputs in a `<form></form>`. When you have a form with a button of type="submit" it will automatically submit it when enter key is pressed.

```
<form id="calculatorForm">
     <div class="checker">
        <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="Enter first num"> <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="oper" placeholder="enter operation (+,-,/,or*)"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="Enter second num"> <br><br>
        <button type="submit"  onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><br><br>
        <button type="submit" onclick="refreshPage()">Refresh</button>
     </div>
   </form>
```

By just doing this the page will reload after submitting the form. To prevent this you can add this to your javascript code and it will not reload the page.

```
var form = document.getElementById("calculatorForm");
function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
form.addEventListener('submit', handleForm);
```

Jsfiddle demo https://jsfiddle.net/szndvroe/

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your inputs and submit button inside of a `<form>`, you have have <kbd>Enter</kbd> work "automagically" `onsubmit`.

Also, your calculation should occur within its own function.

```js
const messageEl = document.getElementById('message');
const form = document.forms.calculator;

const calculate = (operator, left, right) => {
  switch (operator) {
    case "+": return left + right;
    case "-": return left - right;
    case "*": return left * right;
    case "/": return left / right;
    default: return null;
  }
};

function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Interrupt the event

  const
    num1 = +form.elements.num1.value,
    operator = form.elements.oper.value,
    num2 = +form.elements.num2.value,
    result = calculate(operator, num1, num2);
  
  if (result != null) {
    messageEl.textContent = `Result is: ${result}`;
  }

  return false; // Prevent page navigation
}
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h3>Mini calculator</h3>
<form name="calculator" onSubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <div>
    <input type="number" name="num1" placeholder="Enter first number" step="0.01">
    <input type="text" name="oper" placeholder="Enter operator (+, -, /, or *)">
    <input type="number" name="num2" placeholder="Enter second number" step="0.01">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
<hr />
<p id="message" class="message"></p>
```

You could also make your operator input a `<select>`:

```html
<select name="oper">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select an operator</option>
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="/">/</option>
  <option value="*">*</option>
</select>
```